# I would like to use tab to switch page in my project . project uses react-redux and react -router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router, material-ui

https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/

I am using react - redux.

I would like to use a panelTab in materia ui to switch React Page.

when tab is clicked

```
<TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
  Item One
</TabPanel>
```

How Should I design it?

```
        <TabPanel value={value} index={0}></TabPanel>
        <Route
            exact
            path="/pageA"
            component={PageAContainer}
          ></Route>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
          aaa
          {props.moveToPageB()}
          {/*<Route exact path="/pageB" component={PageBContainer}></Route> */}
        </TabPanel>
```

Comment: why you need to switch the pages inside the Tabs, you can use that component directly and it will display based on the tab selection

Answer (score 0):

You can use Link from react router dom package. So in your tab you can add the below code

```
<TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
  <Link to="/pageA">Page A</Link>
</TabPanel>
```

Comment: No offence , the way of using LINK seems not correct.   (JSX attribute) to: string
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> & Pick<TypographyProps, "color" | ... 261 more ... | "innerRef"> & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.

Comment: Link Component doesn't have ”to”　props.

Comment: its basically the anchor tag with href attribute

Comment: I am sorry. I cound not make sense... you are saying about HTML  A HREF  TAG?

Answer (score 0):

Create main layout like :

```
<header> your tabs </header>   
//pass your routes here 
 <Switch>
  <Route></Route>  
  <Route></Route>  
<Switch/>
```

Header contain multiple tab and tab has link to particular route like

```
   <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
    <Link to="YOUR_ROUTE_NAME">
     Item One
    </Link>
   </TabPanel>
```

So, we can access our links in header and our layout will change as per our tab click

Comment: For more you can refer my project https://github.com/karenaprakash/books_review/tree/master/Frontend

Comment: As far as I can see ,https://material-ui.com/api/link/
Link - component doesn't have Props .

Comment: you can use any link.react-router also provide Link

Comment: I'm afraid to say ... not   Where Should I import that Link ?

Comment: Don't afraid. tell me what you have completed for your app till now

Comment: it seems that There are no Link component in React-router.   Compiler says "Attempted import error: 'Link' is not exported from 'react-router'."

Comment: Error messages say  tiny-invariant.esm.js:12 Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>